# create azure function through code and not through the GUI

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function that I have 3 different environments for dev, staging and prod.

I currently have a git kudu remote for each environment and if I push to that remote then the code gets deployed.  I could not find anything OOTB in azure functions for this.

One really annoying thing is that each time I create a new function or environment, then I am adding my config, such as CORS and environment variables through the GUI which is not reproducible.

How could I create my function through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code) might be the right way to go. ARM = Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: I haven't used them myself yet, but I heard that they have a steep learning curve. That's why I'm setting up my new environments manually like OP does.